# Is there a way to visit Quora in mobile URL when I'm on desktop?

Tags: url, mobile, quora

I'm on desktop and would like to visit Quora as I visit it in mobile. Is there a way to do so? What URL should I use?

Comment: Is there any specific reason to visit Quora on mobile using a link while they have given a good mobile app?

Comment: Quora is so nagging, but I can't turn off all of their Javascript. For example, I can't click to extend the collapsed answer without turning it on. I hope that on the mobile version the site is less annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply change your browser's [User Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#Format_for_human-operated_web_browsers) to that of a mobile browser. Quora reads the User Agent when you load the page to determine which version of the page to show.

There are various tools to help with this (Chrome or Firefox add-ons, for example), or you can use the [browser's built-in features](http://osxdaily.com/2013/01/16/change-user-agent-chrome-safari-firefox/) to set it manually.

Once you set your User Agent and reload the page, you should see the mobile version of the page loaded instead of the desktop equivalent.

Comment: Have you tested it?

Comment: Yes. [Here's Quora with a desktop User Agent](http://i.imgur.com/VvNrxBx.png) and [here's mobile](http://i.imgur.com/k90zU1W.png).

Comment: For Firefox, you can use the [UAControl](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/uacontrol/) add-on to specify which site you want to switch the user agent